# How to clear SharedPreferences during Logout?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, logout, android-sharedpreferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("UID", jobj1.getString("admin_id").toString());
editor.apply();

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
toast.show();
Intent i1=new Intent(Login.this,DashBoard.class);
startActivity(i1);
finish();
```

---

This is my logout code using Intent, I want to clear the `SharedPreference` when I click logout button.

```
case "Logout":
              Intent i5=new Intent(context1, Login.class);
              i5.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              context1.startActivity(i5);
              ((DashBoard)context1).finish();
              Toast.makeText(context1,"Logout",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: have you tried searching before asking?

Comment: yes sir, but code not work for me.

Comment: What should the code do? Which code does not work? And what exactly goes different?

Comment: `code not work for me` show which code you tried.

Comment: logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching News Feed Screen

             SharedPreferences preferences =getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
             editor.clear();
             editor.commit();
             finish();
 });

Comment: you are trying to clear different preferences. You need to clear same as you are writing to.

Answer (score 4):

Use `clear()` method:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
editor.clear()
editor.apply()
```

Answer (score 1):

For API 24 (Nougat) or higher you can just call [deleteSharedPreferences(String name)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteSharedPreferences(java.lang.String))

```
context.deleteSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFS");
```

However, there is no backward compatibility, so if you're supporting anything less than 24 you can use `apply()` for non-blocking asynchronous operation.

```
context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().apply(); //apply() for non-blocking asynchronous operation
```

Or in your case,

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit().clear().apply();
```

**commit() :** writes the data synchronously (blocking the thread its called from) and returns about the success of the operation.

**apply() :** schedules the data to be written asynchronously. It does not inform you about the success of the operation.

[As per official docuement,](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) If you don't care about the return value and you're using this from your application's main thread, consider using `apply()` instead of `commit()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
editor.remove("UID");//your key
editor.commit();
```

`clear()`  can remove all values from the preferences.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("pref_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.edit().clear().commit();
```

Comment: would prefer `.apply()` instead of `.commit()` , as **apply* is asynchronous call